# How can I use Ngrok for my backend and frontend and database conect?

Tags: vue.js, cors

I am attempting to connect my database, server, and front-end. I am using Express for the server and Vue for the front-end. However, when I try to make a GET request, it results in errors:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://8416-xxx-xxx-xx-xx.ngrok-free.app/get_data' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I am seeking assistance regarding this issue.

Comment: It's unknown what's your FE setup. CORS problem is one of few things that devserver proxy solves, ngrok or not.

Answer (score 0):

CORS errors can happen when your frontend is being served from a domain say `example1.com`, and that is trying to make a HTTP request to a backend which is in another domain say `example2.com`.

In your case, your backend is at `https://8416-xxx-xxx-xx-xx.ngrok-free.app`, but seems like the frontend is being accessed from a different URL.

There are two options to solve the issue:

1. Serve both the frontend and backend from the same domain
2. Configure the server to respond with proper CORS headers which will tell the browser to allow the cross origin (cross domain) requests.

Here is how you can do 2. with express.js (see https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html):

```
npm install cors
```

Now cofigure your application to use cors:

```
var express = require('express')
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()

var corsOptions = {
  origin: 'http://domainofyourfrontend.com',
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200 // some legacy browsers (IE11, various SmartTVs) choke on 204
}

app.get('/get_data', cors(corsOptions), function (req, res, next) {
  res.json({msg: 'This is CORS-enabled for only http://domainofyourfrontend.com'})
})

app.listen(80, function () {
  console.log('CORS-enabled web server listening on port 80')
})
```